# POST Absolute URI is sent to server by XmlHttpRequest when using Squid3 proxy

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, squid

I've faced strange problem now with sending http request from Chrome extension i am developing (normal JavaScript). This's a **POST** request with **XmlHttpRequest** (from `background.js`) with url like:

```
http://host.com/postform/upload
```

I also send this request from normal webpage (not chrome extension), and *important bit* is that if i open Developer Tools and check Network tab for my request (selecting **raw** headers display) i see first header there:

```
POST /postform/upload HTTP/1.1
```

And it works fine before i enable proxy instead of a direct conneciton. I use squid3 on my Ubuntu for this. Only one thing is different between requests when using proxy - and it makes HTTP server return **404 not found** - only when using proxy..

When i force Chrome to work with my proxy based on **squid3** (i use PAC script for this in my chrome extension), my request will not work. I checked many times and did all i could to reduce any difference in request body, and all i have left for now is first header.

It looks like this when request sent with proxy active (from Network tab of Developer Tools, opened from *background page*):

```
POST http://host.com/postform/upload HTTP/1.1
```

I've tried using chome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders API, but that did not help. I also tried to remove hostname from URL in **XmlHttpRequest.open** but this did not help.

Yep, i am sending correct Host and Origin headers in any case. Could this be a problem in my squid3 configuration, or what should i change in my javaScript?

**UPDATE**
Realized now that squid is not the problem in any way, and the problem is that **POST** request contains FULL uri (http://...) instead of "path". **GET** works fine. It's killing me.

I cannot use `iframe` workarounds. What's my problem?

Comment: I understand what causes 404 error on server when using proxy, but i don't understand why anything works (with PAC proxy) fine if request is sent from normal Chrome webpage (jquery/ajax) and not extension backend script.

Answer (score 4):

To use the `XHR` API from within your Chrome extension, you need to request the permission for the target host by specifying its URL in the `"permissions"` manifest-attribute. For example, if the target host (to which you want to send the `XHR` request) is `http://www.example.org`, then your manifest should contain the following lines of code.

```
...
"permissions" : {
    "http://www.example.org",
    ...
}
```

If you have done so already, then obviously, the error is on the back-end part. Also read about [match patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) to allow matching of multiple URLs using a single string - for example, `*://www.example.org/*`.

Comment: @DmitrjA If that is what you have, that's a malformed match pattern. Should be `"*://*/*"`

Comment: @Xan `*://*.org` does exactly what i need. I tried your solution and nothing changed. GET works as expected, POST fails because header contains full request URI instead of "location" (path).